# Nuget as a package manager

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I'm looking to work on an application, an internal toolbelt if you will.

Rather than having users messing around with DLL's for the differing tools (they plug in via MEF) I was wondering if it's possible to jump on the back of Nuget?

I'd build the tools, package them as nuget packages and host them internally and the toolbelt application would then query the catalog, retrieve and extract etc etc.

Does anybody know of a way this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chocolatey uses nuget as an underlying package manager to install applications on your pc.

http://chocolatey.org/

So I'm sure it's possible, but I've not done it myself.

The nuget documentation discusses a command line and power shell reference: http://docs.nuget.org/

Also linqpad, does something similar (in the paid for version), where you can include dll's from nuget. There is a screen shot on this page: http://www.linqpad.net/purchase.aspx

Comment: Useful, but I've seen info around that seems to indicate Nuget.Core can be used for it, Nuget.Core has a bunch of stuff in it all of which has next-to-zero documentation. Appreciate the link to possible leads though!

Comment: Yeah, they're just example applications to show it's feasible rather than how do it yourself. How about executing powershell scripts from your application, it's well documented: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference

Comment: I could do, but it seems to be largely geared toward visual studio. I'm sure there's a way of doing so.

Comment: Good point @Clint you're right it looks geared to visual studio, perhaps the chocolatey source code will be of inspiration: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey